# Supabase Oauth with Remix errors on redirect "You are trying to use a blocker on a POP navigation"

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, supabase, remix.run

After I sign in with a 3rd party auth provider using Supabase Auth, I am not seeing what I should be seeing, that is data visible to authenticated users only. Moreover, I am getting this warning in my console

> You are trying to use a blocker on a POP navigation to a location that
> was not created by @remix-run/router. This will fail silently in
> production. This can happen if you are navigating outside the router
> via `window.history.pushState`/`window.location.hash` instead of using
> router navigation APIs.  This can also happen if you are using
> createHashRouter and the user manually changes the URL.

Now this is puzzling.

Here's where I call supabase auth:

```
// login.tsx
import { useOutletContext } from '@remix-run/react';

import type { SupabaseOutletContext } from '~/root';

export function Login() {
    const { supabase } = useOutletContext<SupabaseOutletContext>();

    async function handleLogin() {
        return (await supabase).auth.signInWithOAuth({
            provider: 'github',
        });
    }

    const handleLogout = async () => {
        const { error } = await supabase.auth.signOut();
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <button onClick={handleLogin}>Login</button>
            <button onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

```
// root.tsx
// ...
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js';

import type { SupabaseClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js';
// ...
type TypedSupabaseClient = SupabaseClient<Database>;
export type SupabaseOutletContext = {
    supabase: TypedSupabaseClient;
};

// ...

export const loader = ({}: LoaderArgs) => {
    const env = {
        SUPABASE_URL: process.env.SUPABASE_URL!,
        SUPABASE_ANON_KEY: process.env.SUPABASE_ANON_KEY!,
    };

    return json({ env });
};

export default function App() {
    const { env } = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();

    const [supabase] = useState(() =>
        createClient<Database>(env.SUPABASE_URL!, env.SUPABASE_ANON_KEY!)
    );

    return (
        {/* ... */}
                <Outlet context={{ supabase }} />
        {/* ... */} );
}
```

Finally, index.tsx

```
import type { LoaderArgs } from '@remix-run/node';

import { useLoaderData } from '@remix-run/react';
import { Login } from 'components/login';
import supabase from 'utils/supabase.server';

export const loader = async ({}: LoaderArgs) => {
    // uses RLS
    const { data } = await supabase.from('messages').select('*');

    return { messages: data ?? [] };
};

export default function Index() {
    const { messages } = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();
    return (
        <>
            <Login />
            <pre>{JSON.stringify({ messages }, null, 2)}</pre>
        </>
    );
}
```

[image: RLS]

Why on Earth am I getting this warning? Why am I not authenticated? It was meant to be this simple app to check out supabase. What to do to fix the warning?

Versions of packages:

```
    "@remix-run/node": "1.12.0",
    "@remix-run/react": "1.12.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.7.1"
```

Edit 1:
I shared the code in a public repo https://github.com/jessaleks/supabase-remix-debug-repo

Comment: Have you tried using @supabase/auth-helpers-remix as documented here https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-helpers/remix

Comment: @RichardScarrott perhaps that could help, but I can see that shouldn't be necessary. See here https://github.com/dijonmusters/build-a-realtime-chat-app-with-remix-and-supabase/tree/main/05-implement-supabase-auth-using-github

Comment: Interestingly, after using the proposed package, it still does not work. I still get the same error. See yourself https://github.com/jessaleks/supabase-remix-debug-repo

Comment: I posted an answer to the question, however, I also noticed you were using the auth helpers to create a browser client, but then using `supabase-js` to make a request to Supabase from your loader. This will not work as your Login component will now be using cookies to store your user's session, and your loader will be looking for it in localStorage (which doesn't exist server-side). I pushed up a PR to your project so you can see what you would need to change so RLS policies will work correctly 

https://github.com/jessaleks/supabase-remix-debug-repo/pull/1

Answer (score 2):

This is a warning that appears when running locally, as Supabase redirects after receiving a token from the successful OAuth process with GitHub. Remix (or React Router) are just logging a warning to tell you that you redirected without using their router, as the application code you are writing should use their router for redirects and things. In the case of Supabase doing this during the auth process, it is safe to ignore